Настроить, как начать работать с Manticore
ii  manticore                              6.3.6-24080214-593045790                     amd64        Manticore Search - database for search
ii  manticore-backup                       1.3.8-24052208-57fc406                       all          Manticore Backup
ii  manticore-buddy                        2.3.12-24071807-45f6b91                      all          Manticore Buddy
ii  manticore-columnar-lib                 2.3.0-24052206-88a01c3                       amd64        Manticore Columnar Library is a column-oriented storage library, aiming to provide decent performance with low memory footprint at big data volume
ii  manticore-common                       6.3.6-24080214-593045790                     all          Manticore Search - database for search
ii  manticore-dev                          6.3.6-24080214-593045790                     all          Manticore Search - database for search
ii  manticore-executor                     1.1.12-24071807-0565a65                      amd64        Custom built PHP executor for Manticore.
ii  manticore-galera                       3.37                                         amd64        Synchronous multi-master wsrep provider (replication engine) (Manticore's fork)
ii  manticore-icudata-65l                  5.0.3-221123-d2d9e5e56                       all          Manticore Search - database for search
ii  manticore-repo                         0.0.4                                        all          Manticore Software APT repository deployment package
ii  manticore-server                       6.3.6-24080214-593045790                     amd64        Manticore Search - database for search
ii  manticore-server-core                  6.3.6-24080214-593045790                     amd64        Manticore Search - database for search
ii  manticore-tools                        6.3.6-24080214-593045790                     amd64        Manticore Search - database for search
ii  manticore-tzdata                       1.0.0-240522-a8aa66e                         all          no description given
ii  mariadb-common                         1:10.6.18-0ubuntu0.22.04.1     

Провайдер установил модуль manticore на сервер https://manticoresearch.com/
Но, не понимаю как начать с ним работать. Хотел бы чтобы на странице поиска, выборка из бд была по нему...
Как это сделать? Необходимо какой та процесс запускать, конфиг создавать...
Все мое понимание как это работает, заключается в том, что модуль создает какой то кэш записей указанной таблицы и поля. И при обращении к модулю, выдает результат наиболее схожих или близких по заголовкам записи...
Блин, как мне сделать свой первый запрос из PHP к нему, как настроить. А там уже само собой пойдет процесс..
Совсем не понимаю как это работает...

Может быть стоит документацию почитать (https://manual.manticoresearch.com/)? Кроме документации, есть интерактивные курсы - https://play.manticoresearch.com/
